# Air drag on moving air

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, estimation, flow, aerodynamics

Assuming we have a $0.6\ \mathrm m$ diameter fan blowing $3\ \mathrm{m/s}$ as measured by an anemometer at the exact exit of the fan (it was actually measured at the entrance), what is the speed of the air as it reaches a plane $0.7\ \mathrm m$ away from the fan? Ideally we would like to estimate the force of the air over a certain area of the plane.

We can calculate the force of the air moving through the fan based on:
$$F=v^2\rho A=v^2\rho\pi r^2$$
$$\rho=1.225\ \mathrm{kg/m^3}$$
$$r=0.3\ \mathrm m$$
$$F=3.117\ \mathrm N$$

There is obviously drag acting on the moving air, along with turbulence. For argument's sake, if we assume the air would move in a "diverging but 100 % laminar" flow (i.e. no turbulence), even though the air may be diverging, all the moving air would still hit the plane $0.7$ meters away. If there was no drag/friction on the moving air, the force of the air hitting the plane $0.7$ meters away would be the same as the force of the air exiting the fan ($3.117\ \mathrm N$).

Even with 100 % laminar flow, there would be loss in momentum due to the drag on the moving air as it interacts with the still air. In that case, the velocity and force of the wind hitting the plane would be less than that exiting the fan. My question is, in this manipulated situation, can we make an educated guess (maybe within an order of magnitude) as to the wind speed at the plane? Can we also make an educated guess as to how much the moving air will diverge at $0.7\ \mathrm m$ (so we can estimate the force over an area of the plane)?

We don't have the ability to recreate the experiment (which was originally used to recreate an actual event) so we need to make a reasonable calculation as to the force of the wind at $0.7\ \mathrm m$ away over a given area. If we calculate using laminar flow (assuming that makes the calculations easier), then we will know that the actual wind speed and force will be less than that due to turbulence. Why the guy didn't think to measure the wind at $0.7$ meters away with the anemometer is beyond me.

We will recreate the experiment using CFD analysis however, I would like to try to come up with reasonable analytical solution for this. Any help would be appreciated.